# are there function to calc magnitude of all pixels in two images?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

i have my code that is about sobel operation

```
        Image<Gray, double> test_x= new Image<Gray, double>(img_gray.Size);
        Image<Gray, double> test_y = new Image<Gray, double>(img_gray.Size);
        Image<Gray, byte> final = new Image<Gray, byte>(img_gray.Size);
        CvInvoke.Sobel(img_gray, test_x, DepthType.Cv64F,1,0);
        CvInvoke.Sobel(img_gray, test_y, DepthType.Cv64F, 0, 1);
        for (int x = 0; x < img_gray.Cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < img_gray.Rows; y++)
            {
                double mag = Math.Pow(test_x[y, x].Intensity, 2) + Math.Pow(test_y[y, x].Intensity, 2);
                mag = Math.Sqrt(mag);
                if (mag > 125)
                {
                    final[y, x] = new Gray(255);
                }
                else
                {
                    final[y, x] = new Gray(0);
                }
            }
        }
        imageBox2.Image = final;
```

this code is taking along time to show me the result

are there any function in opencv to calc magnitude of all pixels without access to all pixels 
by for loop

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmguCv has a function for that. How fast it is I'll leave to you to decide

```
Image<Gray, double> test_x= new Image<Gray, double>(img_gray.Size);
Image<Gray, double> test_y = new Image<Gray, double>(img_gray.Size);
CudaImage<Gray, double> final = new CudaImage<Gray, double>(img_gray.Size);
CvInvoke.Sobel(img_gray, test_x, DepthType.Cv64F,1,0);
CvInvoke.Sobel(img_gray, test_y, DepthType.Cv64F, 0, 1);
CudaImage<Gray, double> xCuda = new CudaImage<Gray, double>(test_x);
CudaImage<Gray, double> yCuda = new CudaImage<Gray, double>(test_y);
CudaInvoke.Magnitude(xCuda, yCuda, final);
```

Comment: it tells me that there are not definition for magnitude in cvinvoke

Comment: It seems like it is in `CV.Cuda` namespace only. Hence called with `CudaInvoke`

Comment: yeah i get it but when i run it gives me error emgu cv unable to find entry point names in dll cvextreme wht is this??

Comment: The issue might be that you have multiple EmguCv versions installed. EmguCv is built with CUDA support by default, so if you have CUDA capable nVidia graphics, there should be no issues running cuda functions. Also I have realized, the has to be a `CudaImage` now that it is passed to cuda functions (answer updated)

Comment: i  thinks there one version only because i am using nuget but i cant understand what do you mean 'capable nVidia graphics' ?

Comment: If you ve installed EmguCv using nuget, there should be no issue indeed. Your graphics card can be (and for your needs should be) cuda capable. This means it can execute cuda "functions" on it. Whether you have a CUDA capable graphics card or not can be chacked [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute)

Comment: maybe i have a Gpu that is not from Nividia it is name is ATI Mobility readon this graphic card can execute Cuda functions or not ??

Comment: Then you dont have CUDA capable GPU. You would have to find OpenCL omplementation, which are possible in OCV C++, dont think its possible in EmguCV

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 'cv::magnitude':

*Calculates the magnitude of 2D vectors.
C++: void magnitude(InputArray x, InputArray y, OutputArray magnitude)
Python: cv2.magnitude(x, y[, magnitude]) → magnitude
Parameters: 
x – floating-point array of x-coordinates of the vectors.
y – floating-point array of y-coordinates of the vectors; it must have the same size as x.
magnitude – output array of the same size and type as x.
The function magnitude calculates the magnitude of 2D vectors formed from the corresponding elements of x and y arrays:*

check this link: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude